# Why does this regex take so long to find email addresses in certain files?

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

I have a regular expression that looks for email addresses ( this was taken from another SO post that I can't find and has been tested on all kinds of email configurations ... changing this is not exactly my question ... but understand if that is the root cause ):

```
/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i
```

I'm using preg_match_all() in PHP.

This works great for 99.99...% of files I'm looking in and takes around 5ms, but occasionally takes a couple minutes.  These files are larger than the average webpage at around 300k, but much larger files generally process fine.  The only thing I can find in the file contents that stands out is strings of thousands of consecutive "random" alphanumeric characters like this:

```
wEPDwUKMTk0ODI3Nzk5MQ9kFgICAw9kFgYCAQ8WAh4H...
```

Here are two pages causing the problem.  View source to see the long strings.

- http://www.ashrae.org/members/page/607
- http://www.ashrae.org/publications/page/2010ajindex

Any thoughts on what is causing this?

**--FINAL SOLUTION--**

I tested various regexes suggested in the answers.  @FailedDev's answer helped and dropped processing time from a few minutes to a few seconds.  @hakre's answer solved the problem and reduced processing time to a few hundred milliseconds.  Below is the final regex I used.  It's @hakre's second suggestion.

```
/[a-z0-9_\-\+]{1,256}+@[a-z0-9\-]{1,256}+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i
```

Comment: Csn you convert your `+` in `++` so they don't backtrack?

Comment: You're collecting email addresses by scraping them from pages...so you can spam people...and you want us to help?

Comment: Can you clarify that comment @ninjalj?

Comment: @mario: have you tested with case insensitivity? For me (PCRE 7.6) (ancient, I know), both Perl and pcregrep w/o case insensitivity are instantaneous, while `pcregrep -i` takes 5.5s on the possesive quantifier case (28s on the greedy case). Also, as expected, atomic greedy takes the same time as possesive.

Comment: @ninjalj: Used `/i` and PCRE 8.12 (now dated too). Actually my previous test probably just failed (php.ini `pcre.backtrack_limit` likely). Run again. Using possesive approach really didn't help much. It was indeed using a reasonable quantifier `{1,50}` which had the best performance impact.

Comment: @mario: same here: `{1,256}` goes down to 1.7s, `{1,256}+` goes to 0.4s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already know that your regex is causing an issue for large files. So maybe you can make it a bit smarter?

For example, you're using `+` to match one or more chars. Let's say you have a string of 10 000 chars. The regex must look 10 000 combinations to find the largest match. Then you combine it with similar ones. Let's say you have a string with 20 000 chars and two `+` groups. How could they match in the file. Probably 10 000 x 10 000 possibilities. And so on and so forth.

If you can limit the number of characters (this looks a bit like you're looking for email patterns), probably limit the email address domain name to 256 and the address itself to 256 characters. Then this would be 256 x 256 possibilities to test "only":

```
/[a-z0-9_\-\+]{1,256}@[a-z0-9\-]{1,256}\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i
```

That's probably already much faster. Then making those quantifiers possessive will reduce backtracking for PCRE:

```
/[a-z0-9_\-\+]{1,256}+@[a-z0-9\-]{1,256}+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i
```

Which should speed it up again.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess would be to try using possesive quantifiers :

```
[a-z0-9_\-\+]+
```

to

```
[a-z0-9_\-\+]++
```

This should fail the regex faster so it may improve performance in these situations.

Edit:

***Maybe*** atomic grouping could also help :

```
/(?>[a-z0-9_\-+]++)@(?>[a-z0-9\-]++\.)(?>[a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/
```

You should first go with option one. It would be interesting to see if there is any difference by also using option two.

Comment: Although there _are_ slight differences between atomic grouping and possessive quantifiers, you really only need to use one. Making all greedy quantifiers possessive should fix Brian's problem, is my guess.

Comment: @BartKiers Yeah I had this conflict myself. I will edit the post accordingly. Maybe the OP could post some benchmarks using both options.

Comment: `{2,3}` should be converted to `{2,3}+` to avoid potentially backtracking once, right?

Comment: @ninjalj Well yes, but I would assume this plays a minor role into the general case.

Comment: @ninjalj, yes, it could also be made possessive, although that wouldn't make a lot of difference since it would never match more than 3 chars. It's more important to make the char classes with an `*` or `+` after it possessive.

Comment: While this helps (see my comment to the question), it seems the main problem is pcre performance with case insensitive matching.

Comment: @ninjalj Case insensitivity literally halves the possible matches right? But you can't really turn it off can you?

Comment: @FailedDev: that was in the ASCII case, Unicode would need to use locale-aware case-folding. And yes, I tried with `LC_ALL=C`. Also, you have it backwards, case-insensitive means it matches regardless of case.

Comment: I benchmarked various answers in the main question body. I gave rough estimates because it depends greatly on the page being processed.