# PHP reading word document to get only Email address

Tags: php, ms-word, docx, doc

Ok , Here is the thing i want a php script to Open and read a user uploaded Word document and take the email addresses that will be in the document and store it to database .

Only the email address ! it will be mixed up like

Email : someone@example.com or like "Email is someone@example.com"

Any format .. One thing for sure is there will be space seperating email id and other words . Can someone help me ? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit broad really. Fundamentally, you need to handle these steps:

#### Upload the word document

You'll need to let users upload a file. There's a [tutorial at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) which should get you started

#### Parse the contents

Office files are complex - each one is technically an entire file system as you can embed images, other documents, etc... The new `.docx` are actually just zip files with some XML - try renaming one to `.zip` and opening it. The old-style `.doc` is a proprietary MS format and while equally complex is far more obfuscated. [This library](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html) appears to convert word files to html which may make reading them a lot easier.

#### Find the email address

I suspect your best chance here is to use a regex to extract the email address from the body. What about if there are multiple email addresses? Here's an [introduction to email regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) which may be of some help. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175859/156755) is for the same thing

For a more detailed answer, you're going to have to provide a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks .. any Regex example ?

Comment: The link to library requires python ? Can i just rename it ? will it work ?

Comment: @ShyleshMohan Sorry, my mistake. Try [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188452/reading-writing-a-ms-word-file-in-php) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371315/156755). Failing that, you might need to unzip/read yourself - [PhpWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) might be a good starting point

Answer (score 1):

Convert Word to text:

```
$filename="file.doc";
$TXTfilename = $filename . ".txt";
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate Word object");
$word->Documents->Open($filename);
// the '2' parameter specifies saving in txt format
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs($TXTfilename ,2);
$word->Documents[1]->Close(false);
$word->Quit();
$word->Release();
$word = NULL;
unset($word);
$content = file_get_contents($TXTfilename);
unlink($TXTfilename);
```

Get all emails in array:

```
$content = "My email is email@example.com"; // it's example. 
$matches = array();
$pattern = '/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9_]+)/'
preg_match($pattern,$content,$matches);
```

Comment: Using COM, you're assuming a windows server with Office installed on it. In addition, Office automation is not good in a production environment - high overhead (a new instance of office for every operation), office still sometimes throws mesageboxes on errors (leaving processes waiting for a user to click Ok before releasing resources), etc... It's not that it won't work but it won't work reliably and robustly.

Comment: True story. You answer is better. Thanks you.

Comment: Only because I've been through the pain of maintaining a system using COM to generate reports for Excel - The damned thing was so temperamental that the server was scheduled to reboot regularly!

Comment: Thanks for the answers , so using COM is a bad idea !

Comment: @ShyleshMohan Read [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757). "Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."